# List of applications, creation date, permissions and 2FA settings for Azure with PowerShell 5+

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm new to Azure and powershell. I have some very basic knowledge of both and some scripting experience but not in powershell. 
Goal : Get list of applications from Azure and all available associated information. Specifically creationdate. Output in CSV.. Applications created in the last 60 days

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-6.13.0 this I havent got to work at all but seems like what I want.

```
$ClientID     = "XCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$ClientSecret = "XCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$tenantdomain = "XCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$loginURL     = "XCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$resource     = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$path = "C:\Scripts\objects.csv"
$headers = "App Name,CreatedOn"

# body for the rest request to get an access token
$body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";resource=$resource;client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}

# get an access token
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$tenantdomain/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Body $body

# if we have an access token, then make the graph call
if ($oauth.access_token -ne $null) 

{

    $headerParams = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}

    $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?select=createddatetime,displayname"


    do {


        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Method GET  -ContentType "application/json"
        if ($response.Content)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

The old AzureRm powershell `Get-AzureRmADApplication` you mentioned essentially calls the azure ad graph api, in azure ad graph api, the [application entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity) does not have the `createddatetime` property which you want. Besides, the new Az powershell `Get-AzADApplication` and azure ad powershell `Get-AzureADApplication` also call the azure ad graph API, so they could not meet your requirement.

Your script is a workaround, the script uses the client credential flow to get the access token and uses the token to call the Microsoft graph API, the logic should be correct.

Due to you did not provide some error information about your script, I could just give you a sample, it works fine on my side.

First, before you get the access token, make sure you have granted the Microsoft graph API permission for your ad app. Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> find your ad app -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> add the `Application permission` of Microsoft graph api(the permission could be `Application.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.Read.All` from least to most privileged, see [`List applications Permissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs#permissions)) -> `Add permissions` -> At last, don't forget to click the **`Grant admin consent`** button.

[image]

**My sample**(the sample is after getting the access token and use it to call MS garph api):

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?select=createddatetime,displayname"
$accesstoken = "eyJ0eXAxxxxxxeHB1Y3FuQktJR2Nyx9Cg"
$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $url –Headers $header –Method GET
$response.value | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]